# I can't center a div over the image

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1zaK.png)i am trying to center the div over the image , i tried positioning the container relative and the elements to absolute but didn't work.The code below shows what i have done till now.The image is a full size background and the container should be centered over it.

```css
.circle123{
    position: relative;
    float: none;
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 0;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;

}
#circle1{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(50,205,50, 0.75);
}
#circle2{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color:rgba(135,206,235, 0.75);
}
#circle3{
    position:absolute ;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(220,20,60, 0.55);
}
.back-bar{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(image.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;       
    background-position: center center;   

}
```

```html
<div class="back-bar"></div>
<div class="circle123">
<div id="circle1"><h2>1<h2></div>
<div id="circle2"><h2>2<h2></div>
<div id="circle3"><h2>3<h2></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cannot see the image, cannot really follow what you really need. Can you provide a more minimalistic example?

Comment: What do you want to do? Center the cirlces in the box? As in left to right or all circles in one place, in the middle of the div? Center the h2 inside the cirlce? Explain a bit more please.

Comment: i added a photo , i want to center the container .circle123 at the center of the image

Answer (score 3):

First, there is problem in your html code, the last `</div>` close nothing.
To center a container with `position : absolute`, the container who has the element should be on `position : relative`. And after that you can center your element with `position : absolute` with :

```
`position : absolute;
top : 0;
bottom : 0;
left : 0;
right : 0;
margin: auto;`
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand what you want, but I believe you want to center content horizontally and vertically on a div that has an image as background. So, here you have.

```css
.image {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 position: relative;
 background: url('https://placehold.it/300x300/?text=This is your image');
}

.image > .centered {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
 <div class="centered">This is at center</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML has issues, `<h2>` are not closed and you have an extra `</div>` at the bottom.

To center each circle in the container, add this to each circle:

```
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
```

Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jLodgoc7/

Comment: what about the h2 , how can i center it?

Comment: @XhimiPg for each circle instead of `display:inline-block` add 

    `display:flex; 
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;`

jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/jLodgoc7/1/

Answer (score 0):

> First step: remove 'Position' from css .
>
> Second step: add float:right for cricle1 and added float:left to
>   cricle3 .
>
> finally add this style(div h { }) on css:

```
#circle1{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(50,205,50, 0.75);
    float: right;
}
#circle2{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color:rgba(135,206,235, 0.75);
    float: none;
}
#circle3{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(220,20,60, 0.55);
    float: left;
}

div h { 
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
}
```